# php date formating help Date format does not give valid date even though it matches documentation

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime, datetime-format

read and have re read the documentation and truly cannot explain why $date1 comes through bad

can someone help? Greatly appreciate it

```
$date1 = "04-16-2013";
$date2 = "2013-04-16";
printf("date1 = %s\n", $date1);
printf("date2 = %s\n", $date2);

$newdate1 = date('m-d-Y',$date1);
$newdate2 = date('Y-m-d',$date2);
printf("newdate1 = %s\n", $newdate1);
printf("newdate2 = %s\n", $newdate2);

$previous_date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($date1 .' -1 day'));
$previous_date2 = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($date2 .' -1 day'));
printf("previous_date = %s\n", $previous_date);
printf("previous_date2 = %s\n", $previous_date2);
```

OUTPUT

```
 date1 = 04-16-2013
    date2 = 2013-04-16
    newdate1 = 12-31-1969
    newdate2 = 1969-12-31
    previous_date = 12-31-1969
    previous_date2 = 04-15-2013
```

Comment: turn notices on. "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /code/79qfex on line 7"

Comment: isn't $date1 bad at line 1 ? I'd expect it to be "16-04-2013"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
> the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
> slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
> separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
> is assumed.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
> dates or [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) when possible.

In your case because you are using the separator dash (-) php consider that the date format is in d-m-y.

**Or a workaround:**

```
$date1 = "04-16-2013";
$date2 = "2013-04-16";
printf("date1 = %s\n", $date1);
printf("date2 = %s\n", $date2);


$newdate1 = date('m-d-Y',strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$date1)));
$newdate2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2));
printf("newdate1 = %s\n", $newdate1);
printf("newdate2 = %s\n", $newdate2);


$previous_date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime(str_replace("-","/",$date1) .' -1 day'));
$previous_date2 = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($date2 .' -1 day'));
printf("previous_date = %s\n", $previous_date);
printf("previous_date2 = %s\n", $previous_date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your case:

```
$date1 = "04-16-2013";
$date = date_create_from_format('m-j-Y', $date1);
echo date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');
```

First the input month-day-year....then outputs day-month-Year

Comment: neither works - 

$date1 = "04-10-2013";
$fecha = new DateTime($date1);
echo $fecha->format('m-d-Y');

gives me the 10-4-2013 --- If I change the date to 04-16-2013 it throws an exception
exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (04-16-2013) at position 0 (0): Unexpected character'

and option 1: gives me the wrong date 04-04-2014 assuming its suppose to be a d not a j so tried that and get 04-04-2014